# How to write a LaTeX syntax in the smartphone easier?

Tags: editors, texniccenter

To write a note containing a mathematical formula in Android smartphones, I use 920 Text Editor Apps. Weakness, due to the limited display on-screen keyboard smartphone, to write '\' (backslash), we need press the button [?123], [=\<], then ['\'].

LaTeX Editor Apps include the [] and some important buttons on the screen, but make the working window smaller .

How to make writing LaTeX syntax in the smartphone becomes easier, eg:

```
    \documentclass typed as .dc
    \usepackage typed as .up
    \begin{document} typed as .bd
```

Note: type [.] (dot) in the smartphone is much easier than type '\'.

Then, when compiling in TeXnicCenter,

```
    .dc reads as \documentclass
    .up reads as \usepackage
    .bd reads as \begin{document}
```

Normally, I am compiling in Laptop using TeXnicCenter. Except for urgent needs, I am compiling it using TeX Portal Apps.

Comment: I see your point, but personally I believe this is some of those things that people shouldn't insist on going "smartphone-wise".  If you want to write a complete document, write it in your computer.  If not, create a pre-existing template that you can copy and then just "fill in the blanks".

Comment: I have used a template, but for writing other syntax, we still need to type '\', for example, to write '\vec{a} \times \vec{b}' and others. Thus, I mean, how to translate . (_dot_) or another character into '\' (_backslash_) in **TeXnicCenter**? Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered swtching to a keyboard designed for coding like [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard)? The `\\` character and others useful for coding are shown upfront

Comment: backslash key is not lost, but to press it need 3 steps.

Comment: and if you change your keyboard it needs one step only

Comment: Why not just write the equation out w/ a stylus, then use a tool like `FFES` (The Freehand Formula Entry System) to convert from the written equation to LaTeX.

Answer (score 1):

A part of problem has been resolved. I wrote in a lightweight markup formats [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), then compiled in a laptop using [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/).